# How to increment the version of package using semantic-versioning, if several bugfixes and a new backward compatible feature have been added?

Tags: semantic-versioning

The semantic versioning system states that a backwards compatible bugfix means that you increment the patch version number (z in x.y.z). It also states that a backwards compatible feature addition should be introduced by incrementing the minor version number (y in x.y.z).

What if both of these things have been added a new release is due? Does one only increment the minor version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semver is a great framework when each addition gets its own release. In this case, you would have ideally released the patch version updates for each bug fix, and then the minor version. However, having collated all those things together, your intuition is right. You can simply bypass the patch versions and bump the minor version. Just make sure to mention the bug fixes in the changelog to help your users know what has happened.

And remember, frameworks are meant to enable you to do things quickly, rather than be strict guidelines. So, nothing out there says that what you're doing goes against semver, it's just adapted to your way of working.